# Can't knit to pdf with custom styles

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

Trying to knit to pdf from RStudio using a custom mystyles.sty file. This used to work fine but now that I have upgraded to RStudio 1.044 I get an error.

Example:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: mystyles.sty
---



## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for             authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown     see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

With this style file:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}

\titleformat{\title}
{\color{airforceblue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{airforceblue}\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{coolblack}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{coolblack}\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Gives me this error:

```
output file: test.knit.md

! Argument of \paragraph has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1290 \ttl@extract\paragraph

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

If I look at the tex file it produces I can't see any missing braces, and there isn't a line 1290. This is using the latest releases of RStudio, R and MacTex. AsI say, this used to work with an older version of RStudio but no more. If I take the includes:... bit out of the YAML it renders without complaint. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is linked to the [rmarkdown latex template](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex) redefining `\subparagraph{}` in a way `titlesec` doesn't like, as hinted at by this answer on [tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103020/extra-when-use-titlesec-package). This is the part of the template that causes the problem:

```
$if(subparagraph)$
$else$
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
$endif$
```

Since the `\subparagraph` redefinition only happens if there is no subparagraph variable set, an easy workaround would be to set it in the yaml front matter. This compiles fine:

```
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: mystyles.sty
subparagraph: true
---
```

This might not be the best solution however: it might be best to fix the subparagraph definition from the template.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [link](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/issues/228) . See twsh's answer. It worked for me. The following is his answer.

> I think that another option is to set the 'subparagraph' variable to
>   true (--variable=subparagraph on the command line). Then titlesec.sty
>   works.

Comment: the link is no longer available.

Comment: @Serk The link stopped working. The answer is quoted though.