# Not able to use titlesec with markdown and pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

When I used titlesec in my markdown document as below:

```
---
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{titlesec}
---
```

when processing it by pandoc, I got the following error:

```
pandoc try.md -o try.pdf
! Argument of \paragraph has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1290 \ttl@extract\paragraph

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

by searching, I found the following work-around for R-markdown:
[Can't knit to pdf with custom styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439701/cant-knit-to-pdf-with-custom-styles)

I wonder how can I implement a similar work-around with markdown and YAML headers?

I also found and verified the following approach would work:

```
pandoc --variable=subparagraph try.md -o try.pdf
```

But it's harder for the user, as one might forget the work-around.

There are some discussion of the work-around https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40574981-latex-template-incompatible-with-titlesec, 
but it's beyond my knowledge

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because the default LaTeX template redefines `\paragraph`. To disable this behaviour, you can use the `subparagraph` variable in pandoc. You could supply this at the command-line:

```
pandoc --variable subparagraph -o file.pdf file.md
```

Or you could embed it in the document's YAML metadata, with any non-null value:

```
---
subparagraph: yes
---
```

From `man pandoc` (and the [user's guide](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-blocks)):

> **`subparagraph`**
>
> disables default behavior of LaTeX template that redefines (sub)paragraphs as sections, changing the appearance of nested headings in some classes

After this, `titlesec.sty` should work.

Comment: When I build [this](https://i.imgur.com/IdyyPHz.png) document with `pandoc -o test.pdf test.md`, everything works fine for me with pandoc 2.2.3.2.