# Change font size of ATX-header in markdown

Tags: formatting, latex, pandoc, bookdown, heading

I am writing a book with bookdown. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to format (e.g. setting font size) ATX-hearder (#, ##, ## etc.). So far, it does not work via `pandoc` or `preamble.tex`.

I have tried the following, with regard to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc).

Unfortunately, there is an error message :

> \usepackage{titlesec} \titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{blue}} {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error message do you get? The quoted text above looks more like the commands you might put into `preamble.tex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is to add a LaTeX preamble to the document. In here, you can define the required LaTeX packages. Two changes are made to the base template:

- We need to add `subparagraph: true` to make titlesec work with R Markdown, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42916124/7347699)
- `#` refers to a level one header in pandoc, and therefore you need to make the style changes for `section` not `chapter` https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Sections_and_chapters

Here is a minimal example

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
subparagraph: true
---


# Section

## Subsection
```

The `preamble.tex` file is saved in the same directory:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{blue}} {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm independent from fncychap package!