# R Markdown Heading/Body spacing format

Tags: r, pdf, formatting, r-markdown

I'm sure this is already out there but I can't seem to find it. How can I change the spacing between a header and body text in an RMarkdown file for a PDF output? I'm not very well versed in TeX or pandoc, so I am wondering if there is a simple way to do this in the YAML header?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the code I have when that I have (I thought this was called the YAML header in the RMarkdown file but I am somewhat knew to markdown formatting so that could be wrong).

```
---
title: "Predicting Diabetes"
author: "Jordan"
date: "April 28, 2018"
output: 
   pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "-V", "classoption=twocolumn"
    ]
---
```

Currently I have created a two-column format of my PDF, but the headers seem to be somewhat spread out, so I am wondering if there is anything to add to the above that can adjusted the spacing between the header and body text. I am inserting a picture of what I mean by the spacing between headers being fairly large.

[image]

Comment: Which particular header are you referring to?

Comment: Jordan, please provide a minimal working (reproducible) example and output format (e.g., pdf, docx).

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to use `header-includes` in order to use the LaTeX `titlesec` package for adjusting the spaces before and after the headers.

Here is the YAML code.

```
---
title: "Predicting Diabetes"
author: "Jordan"
date: "April 28, 2018"
output: 
   pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "-V", "classoption=twocolumn"
    ]
subparagraph: yes
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  \titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  \titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
---
```

Here are the important aspects of this approach:

1. `subparagraph: yes`. [You need this in order to use `titlesec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916124/not-able-to-use-titlesec-with-markdown-and-pandoc). `\subparagraph` is redefined in the [pandoc template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex) for LaTeX by default (the `else$` part in pandoc).
2. [Here is a post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53338/reducing-spacing-after-headings) that explains really well how `\titlespacing` works.