# Change size of section titles in R Markdown PDF

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

Is there a way to change the font size of text of headings in R Markdown?

I know how to number the sections of the article; however, in terms of formatting, the font size of the sections that are numbered `1., 2., 3...` is *too large*. As a workaround, I have been using lower-level headers `### Introduction`, but these have the wrong numbering.

Here is a basic example:

```
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

# This is too big

### This is the right size but are labelled as 1.0.1
```

Comment: Please give a reproducible example with the desired results

Comment: You mean *too big* as in *too large font size*? Which backend are you using? PDF, HTML, ....?

Comment: @RalfStubner I mean too large font size and since it's a paper, the backend is PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place

```
\usepackage[medium]{titlesec} % or small
```

in `preamble.tex` (or where ever you have special LaTeX commands) together with

```
subparagraph: yes
```

in th e YAML headers (c.f. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916124/not-able-to-use-titlesec-with-markdown-and-pandoc)).
 For a more detailed answer we will need a minimal working example.

Comment: The following error is produced when I import the package in the YAML header:

`! Argument of \paragraph has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1290 \ttl@extract\paragraph`

Comment: @SavedByJESUS see the updated answer for a solution to this error

Answer (score 2):

One workaround to this is to change the font size of the section title by including a `css` file. An example is:

> h1 {  font-size: 16px; }
>
> h2 {  font-size: 14px; }
>
> h3 {  font-size: 12px; }

The font size specified inside `h1{}` will change the font size of the header of depth 1 (i.e. `# Section`). The font size specified inside `h2{}` will change the font size of the header of depth 2 (i.e. `## Subsection`) and so on.

Comment: You specify your document is PDF? CSS will only work if you are creating an HTML