# In RMarkdown PDF, change section numbering from "X Section" to "Section X"

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using RMarkdown to take course notes and each major section corresponds to a given lecture. I'd like to have the section headers automatically formatted as 
"Lecture 1", "Lecture 2", etc. Here's basically what I'm looking for.

> ## Lecture 1
>
> Going over syllabus.
>
> ## Lecture 2
>
> Actually learning some stuff

However, when I use RMarkdown's default settings I get the following format (with section numbers preceding names):

> ## 1 Lecture
>
> Going over syllabus.
>
> ## 2 Lecture
>
> Actually learning some stuff.

How do I get the automatic numbering to either:

(1) follow the name (e.g. "October 1st - Lecture **1**")

or

(2) be referenced in the name (e.g. with some sort of pseudocode "`October 1st - Lecture {%section_number%}`")?

Below is a minimal reproducible example of RMarkdown code which can be knit to PDF.

```
---
title: "Course_Notes"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
---

# Lecture
Going over the syllabus.

# Lecture
Actually learning some stuff
```

Comment: My guess would be that this needs to be done with LaTeX, so this could be relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58295/154009

Comment: With ``\section{}`` you should be able to do what you want at least that's how I do it. This is more a question for the ``LaTeX`` website tho. Edit : Mikko answered quicker than me, follow his link!

Comment: Can you intercept the intermediate .tex file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [a TeX answer on altering the section title format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58295/154009), you can use the **titlesec** TeX package to change the section formatting as follows:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1\ \thesection}
```

However, **titlesec** doesn't work out of the box with Pandoc: [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42916124/4550695) shows that you need to add `subparagraph: yes` to the YAML header to get it working.

Putting it together, the following modifications should get you the result you're after:

```
---
title: "Course_Notes"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
  - \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1\ \thesection}
subparagraph: yes
---

# Lecture
Going over the syllabus.

# Lecture
Actually learning some stuff
```